# Invalid fixedDelayString value "${status.schedule}" - cannot parse into long

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, error-handling, spring-scheduled

I have a scheduler which i want to make configurable, so i used fixeddelaystring and fetched its value from MySQL DB. But I am getting this error

```
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'syncStatusScheduler': Invalid fixedDelayString value "${status.schedule}" - cannot parse into long
```

Scheduler

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${status.schedule}" , initialDelay = 1000)
    public void syncStatusScheduler() throws IOException{
.
.
.
}
```

This is the Row in DB from where i want to fetch the time for fixeddelaystring

key                value
'status.schedule','300000'

Excepting fixedDelayString to pick the value but getting the error instead.

Comment: Why would you expect that to take a value from within your DB?

Comment: Spring lookup this value into application.properties not into DB.